# Loading data asynchronously from database

Tags: android, kotlin

Let's assume that I have a function `getData()` returning an array of classes from database, which costs some time to do. I've got an `lateinit var data` where I want to put that data like

```
lateinit var data:MyClass
data = getData()
*do something with it*
```

I need to load data inside OnCreate() function in my app.
How can I do it in android without getting an exception `Network On Main Thread`? Please, give a short specific example because I'm really stuck here.

Comment: It really depends on what are your requirements. In this case probably you need to search for Coroutines and how to use them.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/background/threading

Comment: @abdelilahelaissaoui well I tried coroutines and it does load data but I need for example to put it in recycleview  after it loads

Comment: Then you may want to use LiveData. Do your stuff using Coroutines and then update LiveData's value. Your activity/fragment should be observing that LiveData and updating recyclerview adapter whenever the data has changed

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Threads or kotlin coroutines for tasks that require time to complete and can't be done in main thread, for example network calls.

```
Thread(Runnable {
     //Network or database call method
}).start()
```

Comment: Won't this call an "lateinit property not initialized" exception?